# Charting a numeric sequence in Excel

Tags: excel, charts, sequence

I have a sequence of numbers

```
 0.078
 0.117
 0.077
 0.089
 0.094
 0.102
 0.086
 0.107
 0.090
 0.115
```

How do I chart them in Excel so X axis is index in sequence (1,2,3..) and Y axis is the value?

Answer (score 0):

Select any cell of your sequence and insert chart. It's automatically using (1,2,3,...) as X axis